# taggit module not found error in production server(python anywhere)

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, deployment, web-deployment

I have created blog application and now i am deploying it on pythonanywhere.com
I have used GIT for VCS and GITHUB as a Remote hosting server
(https://github.com/shaileshyadav7771/shaileshproject.git).

I am getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit' although in my local machine on Pycharm i am not getting any error for this third party taggit module.

Please find the below code from server console.

```
       |████████████████████████████████| 7.5 MB 13.4 MB/s 
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 510 kB 12.7 MB/s 
Collecting asgiref~=3.2
  Downloading asgiref-3.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 40 kB 804 kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pytz, asgiref, sqlparse, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.10 django-3.0.4 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1
(myproj) 12:07 ~ $ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
asgiref    3.2.10
Django     3.0.4
pip        20.2.1
pytz       2020.1
setuptools 49.2.1
sqlparse   0.3.1
wheel      0.34.2
(myproj) 12:07 ~ $ git clone https://github.com/shaileshyadav7771/shaileshproject.git
Cloning into 'shaileshproject'...
Username for 'https://github.com': shaileshyadav7958@gmail.com
Password for 'https://shaileshyadav7958@gmail.com@github.com': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 71, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (71/71), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
remote: Total 71 (delta 17), reused 64 (delta 14), pack-reused 0
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.5 MB 13.4 MB/s 
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 510 kB 12.7 MB/s 
Collecting asgiref~=3.2
  Downloading asgiref-3.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 40 kB 804 kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pytz, asgiref, sqlparse, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.10 django-3.0.4 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1
(myproj) 12:07 ~ $ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
asgiref    3.2.10
Django     3.0.4
pip        20.2.1
pytz       2020.1
setuptools 49.2.1
sqlparse   0.3.1
wheel      0.34.2
(myproj) 12:07 ~ $ git clone https://github.com/shaileshyadav7771/shaileshproject.git
Cloning into 'shaileshproject'...
Username for 'https://github.com': shaileshyadav7958@gmail.com
Password for 'https://shaileshyadav7958@gmail.com@github.com': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 71, done.
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.5 MB 13.4 MB/s 
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 510 kB 12.7 MB/s 
Collecting asgiref~=3.2
  Downloading asgiref-3.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 40 kB 804 kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pytz, asgiref, sqlparse, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.10 django-3.0.4 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1
(myproj) 12:07 ~ $ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
asgiref    3.2.10
Django     3.0.4
pip        20.2.1
pytz       2020.1
setuptools 49.2.1
sqlparse   0.3.1
wheel      0.34.2
(myproj) 12:07 ~ $ git clone https://github.com/shaileshyadav7771/shaileshproject.git
Cloning into 'shaileshproject'...
wheel      0.34.2
Username for 'https://github.com': shaileshyadav7958@gmail.com
Password for 'https://shaileshyadav7958@gmail.com@github.com': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 71, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (71/71), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
remote: Total 71 (delta 17), reused 64 (delta 14), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (71/71), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
(myproj) 12:55 ~ $ ls
README.txt  shaileshproject
(myproj) 12:56 ~ $ cd shaileshproject/
(myproj) 12:57 ~/shaileshproject (master)$ ls
blog  blog_project  db.sqlite3  manage.py  static  templates
(myproj) 12:58 ~/shaileshproject (master)$ which django-admin
/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/bin/django-admin
(myproj) 13:03 ~/shaileshproject (master)$ ls
blog  blog_project  db.sqlite3  manage.py  static  templates
(myproj) 13:05 ~/shaileshproject (master)$ ls
blog  blog_project  db.sqlite3  manage.py  static  templates
(myproj) 13:07 ~/shaileshproject (master)$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit'
(myproj) 13:07 ~/shaileshproject (master)$
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have taggit installed in that virtualenv -- you need to run

```
pip install django-taggit
```

...to install it.

Comment: Thanks! Giles for your help.I have installed and now i am not getting error for taggit.
Now i'm getting :

Error running WSGI application
2020-08-08 17:05:08,554: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shaileshproject'
2020-08-08 17:05:08,554:   File "/var/www/shaileshyadav_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 65, in <module>
2020-08-08 17:05:08,554:     django.setup()
2020-08-08 17:05:08,555: 
   File "/home/shaileshyadav/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-08-08   configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)

Comment: OK, glad to hear you worked it out.  What turned out to be the problem?